# ContentProvider: Expose options through URI or by call method?

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I have a content provider which I need to teach to keep a journal detailing all operations for synchronization purposes (i.e., provider is asked to do an update => it does the update and logs in the journal that the update occurred). During the actual synchronization however, journaling needs to be turned off.

How do I best expose toggling the journaling functionality?

a) By introducing a special new URI, e.g. content://<authority>/journaling which I could then write either 0 or 1 to, turning toggling off and on.

b) By using the [`call(String,String,Bundle)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#call%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) mechanism offered by `ContentProvider`.

Which is the more appropriate mechanism to use?